# min/max val changes without cause

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I've been racking my brain on this one and can't figure it out. When figuring out the min and max #'s from an array of numbers entered by the user,  the min value changes on 4th or 5th interation to a number that is not the minimum value. I keep trying to slowly go through and see what is happening, but maybe I've been looking at this for way too long.  Any assistance would be of great appreciation.

```
 public class average2
 {
    public static void main (String [] args)  
    {      


    double[] scores   = new double [25];
    double max= 0 ;
    double min = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double score= 0;
    double average = 0; 
    int    i;


   while ((count < 25)&&((score=IO.readDouble("Enter Scores, -1 to   Quit"))  >0))      
   {  {scores[count++]=score;}


         min= scores[0];
         max = scores[0];  
        for (i=0;i<scores.length; i++)    
        if (score > max)
           { max = score;
           min = min;}
        if (score < min)
           { min = score;}


         sum = sum + score;      
         average = sum /scores.length;


              System.out.println(score); //this line is for testing purposes only 
              System.out.println("Max is " + max);
              System.out.println("Min is " + min);
              System.out.println("The sum of the scores is " + sum);
              System.out.println("The average of the scores is " + average);



              count = count + 1;

     }// end while loop


  }// end main                    

}//end class
```

Comment: What does `min= scores[0];` do and when?

Answer (score 1):

Always remember that if you don't use a `{}`, only *one* line of code will be run in `for`. So a good coding style is **always use {}**!

```
for (i=0;i<scores.length; i++){
    if (score > max) { max = score; min = min;} 
    if (score < min) { min = score;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is missing braces so your second `if` isn't contained in the immediate block.

```
for (i=0; i < scores.length; i++) {    
    if (score > max) { 
        max = score;
        // min = min;
    }
    if (score < min) { 
        min = score;
    }
}
```

You *could* contain that in immediate blocks using an `else if` like

```
for (i=0; i < scores.length; i++)
    if (score > max)
        max = score;
    else if (score < min) 
        min = score;
```

I would suggest you prefer to use braces as it avoids exactly the error your posted version had.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm reading it wrong, your while loop 
`while ((count < 25)&&((score=IO.readDouble("Enter Scores, -1 to   Quit"))  >0))

   {  {scores[count++]=score;}`

only encompasses updating the score. So when you go and compare min and max to score, it will only reflect that of the last entered number.

i.e, if I enter 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, -1
your "score" value will be 2 and will not change because it is never updated every time a new input is given.  So when you compare score[0] with score, it will be comparing the value 5 with 2 and set MAX to 5 because score[0] = 5 and score = 2. MIN will be 0 because score[0] < score.

Best way to update the value would be to enclose the for loop in brackets as mentioned above and iterate through the array of scores instead of just comparing the "score".

```
 for (i=0;i< count; i++) {   
    if (score[i] > max) {
       max = score[i];
       min = min; }
    if (score[i] < min) {
        min = score[i];}
  }
```